# Database remote access doesn't work with school internet

Tags: python, mysql, remote-access

I'm using a database from freesqldatabase.com with Python (MySQLdb)

```
db= mysqldb.connect(host='sql2.freesqldatabase.com',user='xyz',passwd='xyz',db='xyz')
```

The code does work with home internet ( I tried with 3 different ones). However, it doesn't work with school network.

```
Can't connect to MySQL server on 'sql2.freesqldatabase.com' (10061)
```

Any suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: Ask your school's network administrator.

Comment: Firewall could be blocking access to the port - that's not something you can control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the error output, this probably means the port is filtered at some level, possibly at your school if they are using a proxy or a firewall. You could use some commandline tools to test port access, like [telnet on windows](https://support.terranetwork.net/web/knowledgebase/131/Using-telnet-to-check-port-access.html) or [nmap on linux](http://forum.linuxcareer.com/threads/1634-How-do-I-ping-a-specific-port-of-a-remote-server). Contacting your administrator is probably a good idea.